# flutter firebase affichage de la liste de utilisateurs et redirection tchat

Tags: arguments

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthenticationService _auth = AuthenticationService();
  // final AppUserData user;
  // HomeScreen({required this.user});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    NotificationService.initialize();
    final currentUser = Provider.of<AppUser>(context);
    final user = Provider.of<AppUser>(context);
    if (user == null  ) return Loading();
    if (currentUser == null) throw Exception("current user not found");
    final database = DatabaseService(user.uid);
    return
      StreamProvider<List<AppUserData>>.value(
      initialData: [],
      value: database.users,
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              floating: true,
              pinned: true,
              snap: false,
              centerTitle: false,
              title: const Text('meetiou'),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
              bottom: AppBar(
                title: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 40,
                  color: Colors.greenAccent,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Search for something',
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                          suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // Other Sliver Widgets
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                Container(
                  height: 800,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                        // bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                        // bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(30.0)
                    ),
                    color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  ),
                  // child: UserList(),
                //TODO GESTURE DETECTOR
                  child: GestureDetector(
onTap: () {
if(currentUser.uid == user.uid) return;
Navigator.pushNamed(
context,
'/tchat',
arguments: ChatParams(user.uid, user ),
);
},
child: Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
child: Card(
margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0,left: 5.0,right: 5.0,bottom: 2.0),
child: ListTile(
leading: Icon(Icons.person,
size: 60.0,),
// Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png"),
title: Text(currentUser.name),
subtitle: Text('drink ${currentUser.waterCounter} cup of water'),
),
)
),
)
                ),
              ]),
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

je recois toujours trois erreurs

1. error: The argument type 'AppUser' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AppUserData'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [flutter_app] lib\screens\home\home_screen.dart:103)
2. error: The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'AppUser'. (undefined_getter at [flutter_app] lib\screens\home\home_screen.dart:114)
3. error: The getter 'waterCounter' isn't defined for the type 'AppUser'. (undefined_getter at [flutter_app] lib\screens\home\home_screen.dart:115)